# escape % character in Python

Tags: python, django, string, escaping, design-patterns

I have the following string in python, which is then rendered in a template with Django.

```
link_string = '<a href="/search/?q=%23%s"> %s </a>'
```

It is a link to a search url where %23 is '#', because I'm trying to search objects with #hashtag.

I intend to interpolate this string with 2 values, %s after the %23 and another one:

```
link_href = link_string % ('hashtag_value', 'Link Name')
```

What would be the proper way to obtain the following final string:

```
<a href="/search/?q=%23hashtag_value"> Link Name </a>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you absolutely have to urlencode the pound sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
link_string = '<a href="/search/?q=%%23%s"> %s </a>'
```

Answer (score 3):

`%` is escaped using double percent `%%`.

Answer (score 1):

Just type `%` character twice

```
link_string = '<a href="/search/?q=%%23%s"> %s </a>'
```